# Error in running Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

I am new to R and Shiny. I have gone through the very basic example of Shiny from [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson1/). I am running it on my virtual machine.

When i ran the given code, it gives no result but shows the following message " Listening on 127.0.0.1 : 3168 "
The first question is how to change this default IP??
And the next is why it is not producing any result??? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Pass in something different here: `runApp(host="127.0.0.1", port=3168)`.  Then point your web browser to the host and port (http://127.0.0.1:3168 in your example)

Comment: @GSee  its running. Thank you.. :)